# Problema al llamar otra ventana en Python

Tags: python

Tengo un botón el cual debe llamar otra ventana en python pero la interfaz aparece todo en blanco y el cmd me muestra esto 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Donde está el botón *

```
from tkinter import *
from creditos import *

 raiz = Tk()
 raiz.title("Test escolar");
 raiz.resizable(0, 0)
 raiz.configure(bg = '#CAA942')
 raiz.geometry("900x500")

 imagen = PhotoImage(file = "fondo.png")
 fondo = Label(raiz, image = imagen, bg = '#CAA942').place(x = 0, y = 0)

 imagen2 = PhotoImage(file = "user.png")
 fondo2 = Label(raiz, image = imagen2, bg = '#CAA942').place(x = 730, y = 160)

 lblmen = Label(text = "Test vocacional", font = ("Times New Roman", 25), bg = 
 '#CAA942').place(x = 250, y = 0)
 lbldescripcion = Label(text = "Su interfaz dinámica hará que el aspirante no 
 desvíe su atención,debido a que hace" + '\n'
      "más interesante el proyecto y menos tedioso realizar este tipo de 
 examinaciones," + '\n'
      "esto ocasionará que responda con sinceridad.Tendrá un personaje en 2D que 
 esta interactuando" + '\n'
      "con el usuario y el texto se representará en cuadro de diálogos," + '\n'
      " donde el usuario selecciona su respuesta según su consideración..", font = ("Agency Fb", 13), width = 85, height = 6, justify = LEFT, bg = '#CAA942').place(x = 185, y = 150)

lblpalabra = Label(text = "Iniciar", font = ("Times New Roman", 25), bg = '#CAA942').place(x = 45, y = 140)
boton = Button(raiz, text = "Pinchame", width = 15, relief = 'raised', command = (lambda: Ejemplo()))
boton.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)

nxt = PhotoImage(file = "next.png")
a = Button(raiz, image = nxt, bg = '#CAA942').place(x = 60, y = 200)

raiz.mainloop()
```

*La ventana a llamar*

```
from tkinter import *
 def Ejemplo():

    raiz1=Tk()
    raiz1.title("Créditos");
    raiz1.resizable(0,0)
    raiz1.geometry("880x600")

    imagenfondo = PhotoImage(file="pizza.png")
    fondoimg = Label(raiz1,image=imagenfondo).place(x=0,y=0)
    lbltit = Label(text="Créditos",font=("Agency Fb",30),bg="#5B8C34",width=12,height=1,anchor=N,fg="white").place(x=70,y=270)
    lbltxt1 = Label(text="Equipo de diseño:" ,font=("Agency Fb",20),bg='#5B8C34',width=15,height=1,fg="black").place(x=345,y=100)
    lblname1 = Label(text="Freddy Uriostegui Cruz" +'\n' "Jose Roman Aviles",font=("Helvetica",15),bg='#5B8C34',anchor=S,fg="white").place(x=320,y=150)

    lbltxt1 = Label(text="Equipo de programación:" ,font=("Agency Fb",20),bg='#5B8C34',width=20,height=1,fg="black").place(x=315,y=230)
    lblname2 = Label(text="Leonardo Colli" +'\n' "Jose Roman Aviles" + '\n' "Emmanuel Cahuich Ramos" + '\n' "Freddy Uriostegui Cruz",font=("Helvetica",15),bg='#5B8C34',anchor=S,fg="white").place(x=300,y=280)

    lbltxt1 = Label(text="Equipo de sonido:" ,font=("Agency Fb",20),bg='#5B8C34',width=15,height=1,fg="black").place(x=330,y=400)
    lblname2 = Label(text="Leonardo Colli" +'\n' "Jose Roman Aviles",font=("Helvetica",15),bg='#5B8C34',anchor=S,fg="white").place(x=330,y=450)

    lbltxt1 = Label(text="Equipo de documentación:" ,font=("Agency Fb",20),bg='#5B8C34',width=25,height=1,fg="black").place(x=570,y=100)
    lblname2 = Label(text="Leonardo Colli" +'\n' "Emmanuel Cahuich Ramos",font=("Helvetica",15),bg='#5B8C34',anchor=S,fg="white").place(x=570,y=150)


    lbltxt1 = Label(text="Equipo creativo:" ,font=("Agency Fb",20),bg='#5B8C34',width=15,height=1,fg="black").place(x=600,y=250)
    lblname2 = Label(text="Leonardo Colli" +'\n' "Freddy Uriostegui",font=("Helvetica",15),bg='#5B8C34',fg="white").place(x=600,y=300)



    raiz1.mainloop()
```

Además de que el cmd me muestra esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que tengas pizza.png en el directorio

Prueba comentando :

## imagenfondo = PhotoImage(file="pizza.png")

## fondoimg = Label(raiz1,image=imagenfondo).place(x=0,y=0)

Comment: Si tengo el .png en el directorio, esta es la forma correcta para llamar a otro archivo python o hay alguna forma más?